# CSS files compiled by SASS don't get loaded in CRA app after migrating TypeScript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass

I have a React app created with create-react-app. I'm using the package node-sass to load scss files. Previously everything worked as expected. I've decided to use TypeScript, and followed the steps from: https://markpollmann.com/react-moving-to-typescript . Now css files aren't get loaded.

Maybe there's a step missing from the article to load css?

Comment: How exactly are you loading in the css? Are you getting an error of any kind?

Comment: at App.js (haven't written it into tsx yet) I'm importing the scss files

Comment: It sound like an issue unrelated to typescript (especially if you haven't converted where it's loaded yet to tsx). One workaround would be to compile it to css and import the css instead, I can't help much more without seeing any code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, it was just an idea came from the method how to import images, but it solved the problem. Created a file:

```js
//index.d.ts

declare module "*.scss" {
    const value: string;
    export default value;
}
```